# is there any way i can use Application Loader on windows?

Tags: ipa, application-loader

I have just created an iPhone app and need to upload the .ipa file, but I downloaded application loader and I am not able to open it via windows 7. is there any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it came up on my search for a solution to the same problem.  I wanted to share that I found a service that offers remote access to Mac OS called  macincloud.com 
I gave it a try, and it's surprisingly easy.  Documentation isn't great, but it's not that difficult once you have access to the remote mac.  Depending on how much time you're going to need to spend, there are a few pricing options, the cheapest of which is $12/week, but you can cancel any time (we'll see).

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's very late for answering this, but maybe someone need this service. There is a desktop application that allows you to send your generated `.ipa` as well as Application Loader.

See here: http://appuploader.net/index.php

Comment: The website and the app look very fishy. I'm so not comfortable sharing my apple id with them. Could you please confirm the link is still valid?

Comment: @ShashwatBlack, Of course, there may be some risks by using it. But you can change your apple id's password after uploading ipa file.

Comment: to use this app you should pay %(

Comment: http://blog.applicationloader.net/blog/en/2641.html this blog can help users to app specific pass warrning.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Mac OS on your PC Virtual Machine, then easily install Application Loader there

Answer (score 0):

When in search "Application Uploader" in Google, the following result http://www.appstoreuploader.com/ comes at no. 3. Apparently they charge $5 to upload your app.

Comment: They closed shop ... :-(